# css3 / html5 / jQuery - Ticker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering how a ticker like this is created:

[image: Ticker]
As you can see in the image, the ticker is the area with the $.

Is there any method or script plugin, that can generate this? (Not the design, as I will style it myself, just the effect)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the source of the code page instead of posting a screenshot of it? - The good thing with websites is that, most times, you're able to see how something is done, simply by clicking "View Source"... ;-)

Comment: Because it is not from a live page. It's a PSD mockup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?
http://damienhowley.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/jquery-number-ticker/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HTML like this for every digit:

```
<div>
<span>0</span><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span>
</div>
```

and then simply animate the spans with jQuery.

a question: is this screenshot from a real working site or just a design? (I ask because of the text shadows)

Comment: It's a screenshot from a design. It's done with Photoshop :-)

Comment: @oliverbj ok, same story then. except you lose the text-shadow on the bottom of the digit.